# How to work with Instagram?

Tags: wordpress, instagram

I want to make an Instagram sidebar.

This sidebar will show all of my following users' images only.

I only want to do this in WordPress, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To work with Instagram you need the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/).

Comment: Can you explain me little more becouse I dont know PHP work I want the Images of my following user like if i m following you then it will show all images of you and updates of you I have found that is possible with instapress but only 20 pics please tell me the Exact way

Comment: @user1673673 in the above link there is good and easy enough to learn and use the instagram . please first read and try to apply if you will have any problem we ll be happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+instagram+plugin
2. Find a couple of good lists of plugins:

   - http://wpmu.org/10-instagram-plugins-for-wordpress/
   - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/instagram
3. Pick a plugin or two and start figuring out how to use it:

   - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-instagram/
   - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-instagram/
   - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/instagram-for-wordpress/
4. If you still can't figure out exactly how to achieve your goal, ask for help again. Please be more specific next time.